# C# list reference coherency

Tags: c#, list, reference

I have a C# Lists and references question. 
I have two different lists which can both contain a certain object. If I add the same instance to both of those lists using List.Add(Object) and List2.Add(Object), will they both refer to the same object ?
For example, if I access the object from one list, edit some property of that particular object, will the changes be observable "systemwide"?

Actually, this is a question for a GridView, I just have a table of 2 objects and I need to have a table which only contains one of the objects. So can I just create a different list that holds only references to those particular objects ? C++, although more complex, would be less ambiguous here.

Comment: Why don't you try it and find out.

Comment: +1 For Dan-o. Some things you just have to test them for yourself. This site shouldn't be filed with programming language specs.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they will both refer to the same object.  You are adding *references* to the lists.  Conceptually, you're not adding the object itself, but a reference to it.

I am not going to say that C++'s pointers and references are identical, but conceptually they are the same.  In C++ a pointer "points" to the actual instance (in actuality it points to the memory location - all an object is, is an area of memory), and in C# a reference "references" the actual instance.